# Problems to resolve javafx

Tags: ant, javafx, ant4eclipse

I try to build an eclipse project with my ant script. I also use ant4eclipse to import the project.
It works fine until it tries to resolve the following entry from my .classpath file:

```
…
    <classpathentry kind="con"path="at.bestsolution.efxclipse.tooling.jdt.core.JAVAFX_CONTAINER"/>
…
```

ERROR:

```
BUILD FAILED
C:\Users\bob\.jenkins\jobs\BuildTest\workspace\trunk\build.xml:159: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Users\bob\.jenkins\jobs\BuildTest\workspace\trunk\build.xml:70: org.ant4eclipse.lib.core.exception.Ant4EclipseException: Exception whilst resolving the classpath entry '[EclipseClasspathEntry: path: at.bestsolution.efxclipse.tooling.jdt.core.JAVAFX_CONTAINER entryKind: 0 outputLocation: null exported: false]' of project 'test123': '

No 'jdtClassPathLibrary' defined for library entry 'at.bestsolution.efxclipse.tooling.jdt.core.JAVAFX_CONTAINER'.
To resolve this problem, please define a 'jdtClassPathLibrary' element inside your ant build file:

<ant4eclipse:jdtClassPathLibrary name="at.bestsolution.efxclipse.tooling.jdt.core.JAVAFX_CONTAINER">
  <fileset dir="..."/>
</ant4eclipse:jdtClassPathLibrary >
```

if I follow the suggestion by using

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_55\jre\lib
```

as fileset dir I get the error above. And jfxrt.jar exists.

Does anyone have an idea, how to solve the trouble?

Answer (score 0):

The error is because ant4eclipse can find the `classpath` entry of `at.bestsolution.efxclipse.tooling.jdt.core.JAVAFX_CONTAINER` but is unable to find the definition of that container

Now you have to specify the `fileset` tag so as to define the jar files which make up the container. In your case `jfxrt.jar` exactly as the error message says

```
<ant4eclipse:jdtClassPathLibrary name="at.bestsolution.efxclipse.tooling.jdt.core.JAVAFX_CONTAINER">
  <fileset dir="..."/> // the location to the jar
</ant4eclipse:jdtClassPathLibrary >
```

Comment: if I follow the suggestion by using

C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_55\jre\lib

as fileset dir I get the error above. And jfxrt.jar exists.

Comment: If the jar already exists, then may be `JAVAFX_CONTAINER` is not required. This seems to a conflict between e(fx)lipse and ant4eclipse !